# Base url in CodeIgniter HMVC lose www in secondary module

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite, hmvc-codeigniter, .htaccess

I have a question please... this is my project where I use CI 3x HMVC in Linux hosting I have an error:

`.htaccess` is this:

```html
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options -Indexes


### Redirigir la URL sin www a con www ### 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myserver.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.myserver.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myserver.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myserver.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.myserver.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA] #Falta www


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|global|favicon\.ico|javascript)
```

In my file config.php I have this line:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.myserver.com/';
```

When I load `https://www.myserver.com/` in the main "module" (front) I see in all my forms that all have this format:

```
<form action="https://www.myserver.com/controllerxxxx" action="post"....
```

The problem is when I load the `https://www.myserver.com/admin` module... I see in all my forms that have this format...

The difference is in "ADMIN" that my base_url is `https://myserver.com/` Without *WWW*.

*What is wrong? Can you help me please?*

I need to solve this problem and keep my URL server with *WWW* in Front and Admin modules.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*use this instead of that. so replace your `.htaccess` code with this code.*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

*for change HTTP to HTTPS try this.*

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: This code gives me a lot of errors like this: https://www.myserver.com/listar-resumen-estados/1/1 404 (Not Found) and others errors like this... cross domain Ajax... etc

Comment: Thanks... but in my Admin/views forms I see this code: <form action="http://myserver.com/admin/auth/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> And I need http://www.myserver... I see my Base_url is the problem in Admin it changes to be myserver.com ... but in Front(main) module is www.myserver.com

Comment: I give you a screen shot to view my problem, Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!!! my dear friend! It was my error... I put in another config... myserver.com and "admin" was using  this file...Sorry!!! You are so beautiful!!! (I have to delete this conflictive file)